# How to get hyperlinks for footnote when someone uses \footnotemark[] and \footnotetext[]{}?

Tags: hyperref, footnotes

I don't get any hyperlinks when I use `\footnotemark[1]` and `\footnotetext[1]{my text}`, but I do get hyperlinks when I only use \footnote{my text}. I don't want to use `\footnote{}` as it reduces the readability of the `.tex` file.

I am using [`hyperref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). Is there any extra package that I need to load?

I have seen many questions closely related to this question but those were asked long before. Is there any update? Or, is there any new packages to get the hyperlink?

Here is a minimal example where the hyperlinks are not active:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
Here\footnotemark[1] is some text.
\footnotetext[1]{This is a more convenient place to code the footnote text.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)'s [README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README) (section **8 Hints**) mentions: "The footnote support is rather limited. It is beyond the scope to use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` out of order or reusing `\footnotemark`. Here you can either disable `hyperref`'s footnote support by '`hyperfootnotes=false`' or fiddle with internal macros," I think you'll end up having equally-involved code if you can make it work, which might impede code readability anyway.

Comment: Do you really number all of your footnotes manually? Even if you want to set the mark and text separately, numbering them manually just seems masochistic.

Comment: @cfr,Yeah, you are right. I was having this problem too.

Answer (score 5):

Separation of mark and text of footnotes with `hyperref` support is available through the `sepfootnotes` package. It requires you to use `\sepfootnotecontent{<key>}{...}` *before* `\sepfootnote{<key>}`, though:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{sepfootnotes}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\sepfootnotecontent{A}{This is a more convenient place to
  code the footnote text.}

Here\sepfootnote{A} is some text.

\end{document}
```